# Using $\arcsin(z) = -i\log(i(z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1}))$ to compute $\frac{d}{dz}\arcsin(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to use $\sin^{-1}(z) = -i\log(i(z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1}))$ to compute the derivative of $\sin^{-1}(z)$, $\frac{d}{dz}\sin^{-1}(z)$.

Here is my process: 
$$\sin^{-1}(z) = -i\log(i(z + \sqrt{z^2 -1}))$$
$$\sin(-i\log(i(z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1}))) = z$$
Differentiating both sides...
$$\cos(-i\log(i(z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1}))) \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}(z^2 - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} (2z)\right ) = 1$$
$$1 + \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2 - 1}} = \frac{1}{ \cos(-i\log(i(z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1})))}$$
Since we are told that $\arcsin(z) = -i\log(i(z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1}))$, then we have the following:
$$1 + \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2 - 1}} = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1 - z^2}} $$

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: You didn't get the derivative of $\arcsin{z}$?

Comment: @KittyL I more so meant, why is it wrong. Shouldn't I have equality of both sides in the final equation?

Comment: You forgot the $-i$ and the derivative of $ln...$ at the "differentiating both sides" step. But overall, this method wouldn't give you the derivative of $\arcsin{z}$. You should just use chain rule from the beginning.

Comment: Why wouldn't this method work? Also, using the chainrule is way more logical than what I attempted. Wow.

Comment: What you did already involve chain rule, but the answer does not have $\arcsin$, that's why it does not work. Also the problem ask you to use this way in order to avoid the inverse approach.